# Calling a method without a namespace

Tags: c++

I'm just browsing a C++ code and I noticed something. In a source file main.cpp

```
std::cout << converter();
```

Then I looked for the converter definition. There is no namespace and class name. Then I saw in tool.cpp

```
using namespace Ccon::converter;
```

The definition is in the Ccon.cpp file.

Why the main.cpp can call `converter()`?

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Search for "Argument dependent lookup".

Comment: Read a good book about C++ is my advice

Comment: Search the internet for `using namespace c++` is my advice.

Comment: There must be a definition of the function (or class) `converter` somewhere in a file included by `main`. Have you checked all the include files (and their include files recursively)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please see this link for argument-dependant name lookup: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup

When the compiler is unable to find an unqualified `converter()` it will look for available namespaces and uses them if the name and the signature matches.

In this case, main.cpp includes Ccon.h header file I suppose, which defines this namespace, so it looks into that for a `converter()` with a void argument.

Comment: Does that apply here? There are no arguments to converter?

Comment: The way you explain argument-dependent lookup, it's got nothing to do with arguments. In fact if this was true, namespaces wouldn't have any meaning whatsoever.

Comment: I mentioned signature as in function signature, the function's name, plus input arguments' type and the output type. No arguments would be a signature. Yes, jogojapan, if you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup#Criticism , it talks about namespaces becoming less strict because ADL and this is a criticism of ADL